# 'system.Action' is not a valid windows runtime parameter type

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp

In the uwp c# Windows Runtime Componment project, I want to expose a api that webview js can call it with some callback.
So I am trying:

```
// c#
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.AllowForWeb]
public sealed class xx{
    public void setOnChange(string name,System.Action action) {
       xxx
    }
}
// js
windows.xx.setOnChange("js",function(){xxx});
```

Then I got 'system.Action' is not a valid windows runtime parameter type error.

Then I try another way:

```
//c#
public delegate void Action();
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.AllowForWeb]
public sealed class xx{
    public void setOnChange(string name,Action action) {
       xxx
    }
}
// js
windows.xx.setOnChange("js",function(){xxx});
```

The c# can compile , and setOnChange get called, but js do not called.

Answer (score 1):

Finially I find a solve:

```
//c#
[Windows.Foundation.Metadata.AllowForWeb]
public sealed class xx{
    public void setOnChange(string name,EventHanlder<Object> action) {
       xxx
    }
}
// js
windows.xx.setOnChange("js",function(){xxx});
```

I guess EventHanlder<Object> is a special type in Windows Runtime Componment.

Ps: I have read document of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/raising-events-in-windows-runtime-components .
Then I find that it can be done with a class wrap with event handler. It have a lot of code both in js and c#, then I try embed the event handler into parameters, then it works. A hidden/undocument feature of uwp?

Comment: Hmmm. Yep, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.eventhandler it's actually a Windows Runtime library.  Not so sure how you write the class wrap so I cannot be sure that is the feature you mentioned.

Comment: @Barry Wang - MSFT As I have tried in the question, it is not work when I just define a delegate type myself in the Windows Runtime Componment project, but this delegate type in Windows Runtime library is work. So I call it hidden feature.